# How mutate in Rstudio columns that have same pattern in column names?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question that may be very simple, but I still haven't managed to solve it.

I have a data.frame with multiple columns, with the following structure in the column names: `NDVI_20180506, NDVI_20180526, NDVI_20180917, NDVI_20180929, NDVI_20181008, NDVI_20181126 ...`
I would like to create a new column every time a similar pattern appears in the column name ("`NDVI_201805`").

For example: `NDVI_May` (column name) and that the column contains the average of the columns `NDVI_20180506`, `NDVI_20180526`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Generating some data:

```
dat <- tibble(NDVI_20180506 = rnorm(10),
              NDVI_20180526 = rnorm(10),
              NDVI_20180917 = rnorm(10),
              NDVI_20180929 = rnorm(10),
              NDVI_20181008 = rnorm(10),
              NDVI_20181126 = rnorm(10))

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% # Turn to long format to manipulate variable names
  separate(name, c("name", "date"), "_") %>% # Separate date from variable name
  mutate(date = ymd(date), # Set to date
         month = format(date, "%B")) %>% # Extract the month's name
  unite(name, name, month, sep = "_") %>% # Merge variable name with month's name
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>% # Average by variable
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) # Bring back to wide format

  NDVI_May NDVI_November NDVI_October NDVI_September
     <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1    0.137         0.258       -0.454         0.0115
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil for your anwer.

However the solution is not complete, may be wecause I omited  information. 

I add a dataframe with the information. 

I want calculate the average for all rows when I have two or plus Vegetation Index in a same month. 

If I have only one Vegetation Index in a month the result will be the same value in these month. 

I need only one value of Vegetation Index  for month for all rows.

Comment: If it takes an average of just one value, it will return that value, so I'm not sure what is missing. Otherwise, I'm not understanding the problem properly, and you'll need to ask a new question with the full scope of the problem.

Comment: Sorry my comment was incomplete